# Validation, Page events and ViewState

Tags: asp.net, events, validation

i have two buttons on the page. One button is responsible for text fields validation that are to do with registration and the other with loging in. The problem was when i press one of the buttons it refreshes the page and shows all the invalid fields (i dont want the registration fields to be checked by the RequiredFieldValidator whent the user presses the login button).

so what i did i used the initialization event.. to prevent this from happening...

```
    static bool oneButtonPressed;
  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (oneButtonPressed)
        {
            REgisterAge.Visible = false;
            RegisterAge2.Enabled = false;
            RegisterAge3.Enabled = false;
            RegisterPassword.Enabled = false;
            RegisterPassword2.Enabled = false;
            RegisterEmail.Enabled = false;
            RegisterEmail2.Enabled = false;    
        }
        else
        {
            EntryPasswordRequiredFieldValidator10.Enabled = false;
            EntryNameEntryRequiredFieldValidator9.Enabled = false;



        }

    }

    protected void entry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oneButtonPressed = true;
    }
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oneButtonPressed = false;
    }
}
```

The probelm here is that the bool is always false when the page is posted back and loads again.. i do remember my teacher saying i could either use a ViewState or a static variable/method to preserve my values. Am i being wrong here.. do i have to use the ViewState?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you assign a validationgroup to each of the fields + the relevant submit button.
Different validation groups will ensure that validation won't fire on the irrelevant form.

```
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" ValidationGroup="vRegistration"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" ValidationGroup="vRegistration"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Awesome. your answer has helped me a lot